# How to access vuex state objects?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I try to duplicate an object from the vuex state. My state is structured like that:

```js
state = {
  trips: [
    { date: '01.01.2017', driver: 'John Doe' },
    { date: '03.01.2017', driver: 'Mike Astor' }
  ]
```

But the object `state.trips` from the getter doesn't return the array of trip objects instead an array ob objects where the properties are reactiveGetter and reactiveSetter.

If I pass this array object to an eventhandler which should call an action and mutate the store (duplicate the trip) it is not possible to access the properties.

Duplicate action/mutation:

```js
/* actions.js */
export const duplicateTrip = ({ commit }, payload) => {
  console.log(payload)
  const trip = {
    date: payload.date,
    driver: payload.driver
  }
  commit('DUPLICATE_TRIP', { trip })
}     

/* mutations.js */
export default {
  DUPLICATE_TRIP (state, message) {
    state.trips.push(Object.assign(message))
  }
}
```

The action is called from my component template:

```html
<li v-for="trip of trips">{{trip.date}}<button class="btn btn-default" v-on:click="duplicateTrip(trip)">Duplicate</button></li>
```

The trip object which my actions receives looks like:

[image]

Comment: What's the error message exactly? "push is not a function" or something? Could it be that the problem is that you put an object in an object? Try `commit('DUPLICATE_TRIP', trip)`

Comment: The example works, but the pushed objects is not displayed correctly. The output is empty.

Comment: Updated my comment. Is this the problem?

Comment: Added an image to my question which shows the trip object which I receive from the state. It's not clear for me how to copy that object because there a NO properties. Only functions of reactiveGetter/reactiveSetter.

Comment: This is expected: Please read this for understanding this: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html. I guess your UI is not updating as you are passing `{ trip }` instead of `trip` to the `DUPLICATE_TRIP` function. Install https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools in order to see the real data in your store.